# MacOS app validating for App Store: Problem with profile compatible with iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store, cross-platform

I'm currently developing cross-platform application in **Qt 5.14** for iOS and macOS. At this moment I have successfully submitted iOS app for the App Store and now I'm trying to do this same for the Mac App Store.

Unfortunately I have problem. When I'm trying to validate archive at Xcode I got an error:

> Unable to process application at this time due to the following error:
>   Invalid Provisioning Profile. This provisioning profile is not
>   compatible with iOS apps.

I have separater profiles for MacOS and iOS base on same Apple ID. I also checked the build settings and there is no information about iOS anywhere.

My Info.plist file and entielements file are also separate for every OS.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct provisioning files set up for your macOS application? Have you tried using the App Loader application?

Comment: @l'L'l No, never use App Loader application. What is that? I was trying to use Transporter app but I can't pick my *.app from them.
I'm sure this is correct provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was Archive app validator in Xcode. I solved problem by using ***Distribiute App*** instead of ***Validate App***